# React-cookie extension doesnt work / Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-cookie

I'm unable to use react-cookie module in my application, for some reason it gives me the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `CookiesProvider`.

this is my package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chain-function": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-password-strength": "^2.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.0.4",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.9.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "validator": "^10.8.0"
  },
```

and my index.js:

```
import './css/bootstrap.css';
import './css/style.css';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';

const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(

    <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
        <CookiesProvider>
            <App />
        </CookiesProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
    rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution with the same problem, and later seems to me setting the version of react-dom to "^16.3.0" solved the problem... might worth a try